# Twig "Unable to add function"

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I'm using twig, and i'm attempting to add a function.

```
        $Func = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('placeholder', function ($title) {
            $this->module->CurrentPage->addPlaceholder($title);
        });
        \App::make('twig')->addFunction($Func);
```

I will get the following exception

```
Unable to add function "placeholder" as extensions have already been initialized.
```

I've checked twice that the "addFunction" is executed before the twig "loadTemplate". So, it does not seem to be the problem.

Does anyone have a hint, or an idea about this? Or what its all about.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add twig functions right after you created Twig_Environment instance. For example, the following WILL NOT work:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->resourceRoot . '/views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => storage_path('twig'),
    'debug' => Config::get('app.debug'),
    'strict_variables' => true,
));

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment' => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block' => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable' => array('{^', '^}'),
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);

$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('widget', function ($widget, array $params) {
    WidgetFactory::renderWidget($widget, $params);
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Because Lexer is initialized before functions are added. You need to make it like this:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->resourceRoot . '/views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => storage_path('twig'),
    'debug' => Config::get('app.debug'),
    'strict_variables' => true,
));

$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('widget', function ($widget, array $params) {
    WidgetFactory::renderWidget($widget, $params);
});
$twig->addFunction($function);

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment' => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block' => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable' => array('{^', '^}'),
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```